# Google sheets copy column function to rows

Tags: google-sheets

What I need  is a function to copy from an entire row into a single column.

```
=a1
=b1
=c1
=d1
```

and not what I currently get...

```
=a1
=a2
=a3
=a4
```

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/7206bd7b32106cca4fb9bf8e9707a9bb.png

I want to make the functions set like that.

Answer (score 1):

With the limited information you provided, I think you might be looking for the `TRANSPOSE` function.

Q2:

```
   = TRANSPOSE(R1:Z1)
```

Comment: No.  Based on this screenshot by OP, http://i.gyazo.com/7206bd7b32106cca4fb9bf8e9707a9bb.png  I'm just giving him a format. Once he gets a hang of it, he could use wherever he wants.